# Best place to get nVidia driver update for CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos, drivers

What is the best place to get an updated nVidia video driver for CentOS 5.5? Is there a CentOS package available that will update it? Or is it best to download it directly from nVidia?

Also, I do not have an internet connection on the machine, so it will have to be a manual download and installation.

Thanks,
DemiSheep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the nVidia driver directly from nVidia, following their directions.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the packages found at [ELRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php).  You will probably need the kmod-nvidia and the nvidia-x11-drv package.